# Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online | macOS Sonoma 14.4

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've had a problem for two days and unfortunately I can't run the Android Studio emulator!
I will tell you all the methods that I tried to solve my problem, which unfortunately did not solve the problem:

1- In the BIOS of my computer, I activated VT-d and the virtualizer.

2- I activated the Use libusb backend option.
[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5TC7.png)

3- The latest version of Android Emulator is installed from the SDK Tools section!

4- In the simulator, I downloaded API 31 and API 34, and from inside the virtual phone, I even set the Graphics option to Software, and unfortunately, the error was the same again:
[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v77FW.png)

5- I disabled the "Launch in the Running Devices tool window" option and the problem was still not solved!
[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aZMn.png)

6- I clicked on the desired virtualizer from three points on Wipe data and then ran it, but the problem was still not solved!

7- Also, I connected my computer to vpn but still the problem is not solved!!

Of course, let me remind you that I installed Nox player on my Mac to check if the other virtualizer gives an error on my computer. Fortunately, I saw that it did not and Nox player works very well and connects to Android Studio!

But I want to test the program on different APIs and I need it to be an Android Studio emulator.

[Black screen simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NJMr.png)

[An error that is always displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyedO.png)